# Default taglibs used within included JSPs for editing

Tags: eclipse, warnings, code-assist

Within Eclipse's jsp-editor, as you all know, I get code-assistance for external taglibs once I defined them. In the project I am working on now a lot of jsps are just included and have no taglib definition in the top which gives me a lot of editor warnings. In the deployment this doesnt matter because the taglibs are defined in the head-jsp.

Is there a way that I can define default taglibs within a project so the eclipse editor will give me code-assist even though I dont include the taglib in each file again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically eclipse expects that TLD files in certain directories, i solved this by putting it
in a diretory like WEB-INF in the project root, by estasblishing a linked resource to the original location.

c. Thomas